# What is the standard method that scipy minimize uses when method is not specified?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

What is the standard method that scipy.optimize.minimize() uses when I do not specify what method I want it to use? I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

seen in the doc "If not given, chosen to be one of BFGS, L-BFGS-B, SLSQP, depending if the problem has constraints or bounds."

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: Specifically I am using bound constrained optimization, the doc isn't really clear on whether it uses L-BFGS-B or TNC. But you are sure it uses L-BFGS-B?

Comment: Ah I see the quote in the doc now. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, it is what it is written in the doc =)

Comment: After taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L481): SLSQP is used for constrained optimization, L-BFGS-B for unconstrained optimization with bounds and BFGS for unconstrained optimization without bounds.